# Is there any way to specify which 'this' I want to use in a JS anon function, similar to how Java does it?

Tags: javascript, bind, anonymous-function

I've come across this problem a few times, and I'm wondering if it can be solved without having to bind the anon function to 'this' in the context of the parent object.

Here is my situation:

I have an array-like object, lets call it 'numline', which implements an 'each' method. It is contained within another instance of an object, lets call it 'numtank'. The current code looks something like this:

```
function Numtank(numline) {
    this.numline = numline;
};
Numtank.prototype.charForElem(elem) {
    return "Number: " + elem;
}
Numtank.prototype.toString() {
    var str = "";
    this.numline.each(function(elem) {
        str += this.charForElem(elem); //But 'this' is called in the contex of the 'numline' instance, which dosen't (and shouldn't) have the charForElem class. 
    });

    return str;
}

var tank = new Numtank(arbatraryNumline);
tank.toString(); //Uncaught ReferenceError: charFromElem is not defined in numline
```

When I ask 'similar to how Java does it', I mean how Java allows you to prepend the class name to 'this' to specify which 'this' to use.

Is there anyway to get around this without having to bind the anonomouns function to this?

Comment: You should use the standard `.forEach` signature, which takes the callback context as second argument

Comment: @Esailija: Makes sense, I wasn't aware that was the standard way to implement a forEach method.

Comment: `.forEach` is native javascript function https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: That's handy when it is available. When it is not, it is way so verbose. I was gonna put a reference to `call`/`apply` but I thought it wasn't answering your question.

Comment: @Esailija: It's not an actual JS array, but a class which provides some internal array functionality.

Comment: It can be used on any non-array as well: `[].forEach.call(document.body.childNodes, function(){}, this)` :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is generally done is to hold a reference called `self`. It is the most common practice.

```
Numtank.prototype.toString() {
  var self = this, str = "";
  this.numline.each(function(elem) {
    str += self.charForElem(elem);
  });
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that there would be a way to specify which 'this' to use, but if it's common practice I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a copy of `this` in another variable.

```
var oldThis = this;
```

The variable will be visible to those nested callback functions.